# Item Count Appearing on Search Engines in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, category-description

When we search in google it displays its description with "Item Counts".

While rich snippets is enabled for Enable Rich Snippet Reviews And Rating ,Price And Instock ,Breadcrumbs, Description.

And also we have enable RSS Feed.

Please see the image of my issue [image]

Comment: can anyone please explain the solution for this problem....

Comment: Are you using a module for rich snippets??

Comment: No i am not using any third party tool for this purpose